# SQL Select statement to get a result in sorted format

Tags: mysql

I need to get information from 3 different tables and display it to a single one.

The three tables and the result table are  as listed below. The trick here is, in Table1, I need to merge all the rows having same s_id and it should result in a valure shown in the result table(category.table1). 
Can someone please help me with this;

```
Table1
=======    
s_id    name    Category    cat_id
-----   ----    -----       -------
1       ABC     Alert       0           
2       DEF     Alert       0
3       EFG     Alert       0
2       DEF     Paranomal   1
1       ABC     Activity    0
3       EFG     Paranomal   1
1       ABC     Paranomal   1

Table2
=======
s_id    dev_name    dev_id
-----   --------    -----       
1       phil        0123010                 
2       adam        0143134     
3       norm        0153322     

Table3
======
s_id    carv_name   
-----   --------    
1       ford
2       vw
3       fiat

result
======
s_id    category.table1          dev_name.table2        carv_name.table3
------  ---------------          ---------------        ----------------
1       Alert/Activity/Paranomal phil                   ford
2       Alert/Paranomal          adam                   vw
3       Alert/Paranomal          norm                   fiat
```

Comment: and what RDBMS are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT T1.s_id,GROUP_CONCAT(T1.Category SEPARATOR '/') as Category,T2.dev_name,T3.carv_name
FROM Table1 T1 JOIN 
     Table2 T2 ON T1.s_id=T2.s_id JOIN
     Table3 T3 ON T1.s_id=T3.s_id
GROUP BY s_id
```

Result:

```
s_id    Category                    dev_name    carv_name
-------------------------------------------------------
1       Alert/Activity/Paranomal    phil        ford
2       Alert/Paranomal             adam        vw
3       Paranomal/Alert             norm        fiat
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d73734/7).

**NB:** For ordering the content of Category in result, replace

`GROUP_CONCAT(T1.Category SEPARATOR '/')`

with

`GROUP_CONCAT(T1.Category ORDER BY T1.Category ASC SEPARATOR '/')`